# Jupyter kernel dies: np.repeat of an array to have the same shape as other

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter-notebook

i am pretty new to this, please excuse if i misuse some vocabulary...

i have two arrays with the shapes:

> a.shape= 1920, 600
> b.shape= 1920, 1400, 600

i want to repeat the array a with its values along axis=1 to have the same shape as b,  but my kernel keeps dying.
i already added a new axis with

> a=a[:, np.newaxis, :]

so i know have

> a.shape=1920,1,600

and then tried running this, but the kernel dies with no error message:

> a= np.repeat(a, b[1], axis=1)

Any ideas on what else to try? Am i using the repeat function wrong?

BIG thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `b[1]`?  Actual value, not what you think is should be.

Comment: `b[1]` is a (1400, 600) shape array!

Comment: In other words, you probably meant `b.shape[1]` instead of `b[1]`.  Note that if you don't intend to modify independently those repeated data, that is if you are doing that to do a boadcast your self, you can achieve the (seemingly) same result as `aa=np.repeat(a[:,np.newaxis,:], b.shape[1], axis=1)` with `aa=np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=(1920, 1400, 600), strides=(a.strides[0], 0, a.strides[1]))`. Advantage is that it doesn't really copy any data, so doesn't use extra memory. It is just a view of `a`, in which it appears to have shape (1920,1400,600), with 1400 time the same data.

Comment: But drawbacks are the same as the advantages: it is just a view of a. Not really a (1920,1400,600) arrays, even if you can read it as such. So if you modify `aa[x,y,z]`, it modifies all `aa[x,*,z[` as well, since they are all the same data (the same place in memory), and it also modifies the original `a[x,z]`, since, again, it is the same memory/data. So, in other words, `aa` should be treated as read-only. But if that is OK for you, you spare both the cpu time needed for the 1400 copies and the memory to store 1920×1400×600 data (which, if we are talking 64 bits numbers, is 13 GB)

Comment: @chrslg your solution seems to work perfectly fine, thank you very much!
It is indeed read-only, for black-white-referencing in hyperspectral imaging.

Cheers!